# Btrfs состояние на 2021

Tags: linux, fedora

Возможно ли использовать btrfs на ssd без опаски, что он умрет через 2 года.И правда ли что btrfs быстрее ext 4

Comment: Предложу своё мнение: да, я знаю живых людей, которые используют btrfs как рабочую файловую систему. У неё есть множество приятных мелочей, как я понимаю, таких, как copy-on-write и live snapshot. Про SSD: как говорится, на всё воля аллаха. SSD прошли огромный путь от дисков, на котрых надо было "экономить, сколько записывать" до современных дисков, о котрых можно просто не думать. Правда, мне кажется, что диски нижнйе ценовой категории работают так себе с момента покупки, да и вообще: любой SSD может умереть. Можно попробовать следить за его "состоянием здоровья",но про это отдельно почитать

Comment: А, ис амое главное: я не думаю, что "здоровье диска" зависит от используемой FS. В современных FS, думаю, всё весьма оптмизировано, и вряд ли от выбора FS зависит "режим работы диска"

Comment: Забыл написать... за счет того, что в btrfs есть copy-on-write, она производит впечатление более быстрой: копирование большого файла происходит "мгновенно". Запись на диск начнётся только в том случае, если Вы начнёте что то менять в копии. Еще - удобно работать со всякими git - репами, так как там много повторяющихся файлов (в разных ветках), а btrfs поддерживает дедупликацию - то есть, одинаковые файлы в разных ветках хранятся на диске физичсеки в одном экземпляре

Comment: Спасибо.........

Comment: через 2 года умирают 10% ссд за тыщу-две рублей на любой фс.) если брать интел - живут без проблем по 8 лет. крушал вроде норм из дешевых

Comment: У меня SK Hynix

Comment: использовал более 6 лет на домашнем ноуте btrfs+ssd samsung pro (и это все под гентой, то есть, регулярные пересборки). Каких то проблем не было, сказать, что оно работало как то быстрее - не могу.

Comment: @S.H. `man git worktree`, не надо будет мучится с копиями индексов, а вот сами рабочие каталоги дедублицировать, это интересно, да. (Не совсем понял ваш термин «ветка», вы явно использовали не терминологию Git)

Comment: @0andriy - может, бранч?

Comment: @S.H. И каким боком файлы в разных ветках (branch) в Git будут доступны на уровне ФС диска?

Comment: @0andriy - Не совсем понял вопос... Как правило, бранч на диске представлен каталогом типа "MyProject_fixBug", "MyProject_addFeature". ну, то есть у меня такой сценарий использования Git. Внутри такого каталога содержиаое на 99% совпадает в разных бранчах. Как раз сценарий для дедупликации

Comment: @S.H. Вы что-то путаете, branches в Git лежат в индексе, а рабочая копия у вас одна. Нету там дубликатов. Вот в SVN или CVS — другое дело.

Comment: @0andriy - спасибо, я плюсанул Ваши комментарии, действительно, что то меня занесло... Тогда другой сценарий: просто проекты, у которых есть много зависимостей и эти зависимости от проекта к проекту почти совпадают. Тогда тоже дедупликация заиграет всеми красками.